# Calling database from a Laravel blade template

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I've got a menu that is visible in the entire website, separated in a section that i call in every layout that i made :

```
         <select class="custom-select">
            <option>All categories</option>
            <option>Bakery</option>
            <option>Fruits</option>
            <option>Eggs</option>
            <option>Sweets and Chips</option>
            <option>hygiene</option>
            <option>Kitchenware</option>
          </select>
```

Is there a simpler way to load and fill the options directly from the Blade template instead of calling the controller in every view that i make just to fill the menu?

Comment: You can call, but this is really a bad programming practise

Comment: start working with components instead of rebuilding everything for every new page.

Comment: Better use view composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is something you want to use in many different places,you could create a [blade component](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#components) and/or a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#view-composers) to load the data.

Comment: Thank you, i'm still learning laravel, i didnt know that components could do this !